# Same Origin Policy - AJAX & using Public APIs

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

I know if on my own webpage, if my user is on :
http://www.example.com/form.php

and I make an ajax request from that page to : 
http://example.com/responder.php

It will fail because of the Same origin policy (subdomain is different).

What I am trying to understand is, how is it that AJAX requests can pull data from API's like flickr when the request and server are obviously different.

---

**Edit :**
eg: Why does this code work?

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&;method=flickr...'
```

([Referred this Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy))
Is it using [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-cors-20100727/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are few known methods to work around the Same Origin Policy. One popular technique is to use "Script Tag Injection" such as in [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP). Since the `<script>` tag is not constrained by the Same Origin Policy, a script on a third-party domain can provide executable code that interacts with a provided callback function. You may want to check out the "Tips and Tricks" section in the following article for further reading on the topic:

- [Howto Dynamically Insert Javascript And CSS](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS) (hunlock.com)

You may also be interested in checking out the following Stack Overflow post for further reading on other techniques to work around the Same Origin Policy:

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

---

**UPDATE:** Further the updated question:

Quoting from the jQuery documentation on [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" in the URL, the request is treated as JSONP instead.

Comment: It isn't so much that the element is exempt from the Same Origin Policy as that JavaScript has no access to the raw data returned. It depends on the third party providing executable code that interacts with a function you provide.

Comment: @David: Thanks. Updated my answer to be more accurate :)

Comment: aha! damn, jQuery doing all these tricks handles it in the background! :) NEAT! Love jQuery --- Ref : http://insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html

Comment: The aforementioned article now resides at http://www.developria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html