# AJAX Failing when fetching data from another server

Tags: php, html, ajax

I read AJAX does not work with remote but found solution but still facing
How to do it with Pure AJAX, Any guide??
I searched a lot and tried some methods, but did not get.
When I am using same IP and fetching data ,its working with warning,but when giving another server IP, it does not fetch .

```
function tooltipajax(r_ID) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('span'+ r_ID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://ip here/common/accounteditajax.php?key=" +r_ID,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I tried HEADER

```
header("Access-control-Allow-Origin: http://IP HERE/common/");
```

it worked for local server with ip with warning 
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

But not working with another server ip..

Comment: read the warning: the header is not being sent so the browser is not allowing the request because it did not receive the header, you need to place the header call before anything is output

Comment: but my ajax is above to php code and header is put in php code,so how to manage that?

Comment: either move the php code or use a proxy so you dont need to do a cross site request

Comment: why do you need to do an ajax request to this other IP, there is probably a better way

Comment: AJAX http requests have a something called `SAME DOMAIN POLICY` meaning, that you can not fetch/post data other than under the domain you are working on

Comment: I am having client where information on mouse over, I want to send from my server.Please tell me what way other?

Comment: is there any reason the information can't be on the same server as the html page,(cdn,  third party api)

Comment: Another option would be to use JSONP

Comment: @user, there is no reson for that, but I have 100 clients , I want to change content several times for mouseover, so i wont change on 100 servers

Comment: @orangepill I read JSONP, but unable to do that becuase I have implemented all code with ajax:(

Comment: @learning_programming are you trying to fetch from your own server or another?

Comment: @phpnoob i want to fetch from another server...

Comment: Check out the first answer to this question using the '?callback=' params: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy
As well as this answer for even more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536800/same-origin-policy-ajax-using-public-apis

Comment: I think you should be able to use cURL to do this?