# Unable to make call to a php file located on a webserver from ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to call a php file which is located on a webserver(1freehosting.com) from ajax code which is present in an html file located on  my localhost machine (wamp). I tried all diffrent iteration given below but non seems to be working.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","bcbustransit.uni.me/getdirection.php?q="+str.value,true);
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://bcbustransit.uni.me/getdirection.php?q="+str.value,true);
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.bcbustransit.uni.me/getdirection.php?q="+str.value,true);
```

When i upload the same html file on the same webserver(1freehosting.com) and then make a call it works as specified below.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdirection.php?q="+str.value,true);
```

How can i make a call to a php file on a webserver from my localhost machine ? Is there something i am doing wrong

Comment: Look up something called the "same origin policy."  That's very likely what you're facing here.

Answer (score 1):

Check this question [Same Origin Policy - AJAX & using Public APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536800/same-origin-policy-ajax-using-public-apis) It should be the same problem and has a solution for your problem.