# Hosted WordPress Site in a Subdirectory different server

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, reverse-proxy

We are hosting our blog in a subdirectory (https://domain.com/blog/), not a subdomain (https://blog.domain.com). We are fetching content behind reverse proxy from server b.

Every thing is working fine but I could not make Ajax call.
This is my jquery code.
I tried:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('reallygoodstuff.com/community') !== -1) {
    proxied-ajaxurl = '/community/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    proxied-rgsajaxcall ='/community/wp-content/themes/themefolder/js/ajax-auth.js'
    var proxied-url= proxied-rgsajaxcall.proxied-ajaxurl;
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '#seemorefarvt', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */

    jQuery(this).remove();
    jQuery("#hideonseemorefavt").delay(800).hide(0);
    jQuery.ajax({

        url: proxied-url,

        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'rgsmainjsfile' ,
            query_vars: rgsajaxcall.query_vars,
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery("#showmessage").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>');
        },
        success: function  (html) {
            jQuery("#appendfavthtml").append(html).show("slow");
            jQuery("#showmessage").remove();
        },

    });
```

I get same page which i am on.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536800/same-origin-policy-ajax-using-public-apis

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this is not cross domain call..

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette, you were right it was cross browser call.

Comment: Is the problem fixed? If so, can you post an answer (answer yourself) to explain the corrective steps ?

Comment: no its not fixed.I had to use alternative which is not ajax call.